# how to control over flow of list item in zkoss

Tags: css, zk

Can any one guide me how to control overflow of list item. In code label "Operation Instruction" having a breaf instruction of a customer and i applied maxlength="40" when i restore down window then "Operation Instruction" shown two or more lines and i want it will be in single line only

```
<east id="eastcr" width="70%" autoscroll="true" visible="false" style="overflow:auto">
<groupbox>
    <caption label="Select Account"></caption>
    <separator></separator>
    <listbox id="lstbx" style="overflow:auto" mold="paging">
        <listhead id="lsthd" sizable="true" >          
        <listheader id="lsthd1" label="Sr No" align="center" width="5%" sort="auto"/>
        <listheader label="Account Number" align="center" width="15%" sort="auto"/>  
        <listheader label="Account Name" align="left" width="25%"  sort="auto" maxlength="20"/> 
        <listheader label="Operation Instruction" align="left" width="39%" sort="auto" maxlength="40"/>  
        </listhead>       
    </listbox>
</groupbox> </east>
```

Comment: try with `style=" white-space: nowrap;"`

Comment: @SubodhJoshi Thanks and please post this as an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can use below style

```
style="white-space: nowrap;"
```

What it mean check below

> **nowrap**    Sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace. Text will never wrap to the next line. The text continues
>   on the same line until a 
>  tag is encountered